# How to get previous page title

Tags: nodes

How can I get the previous viewed page title? For example, I visited node/21 then, I navigate to node/22, then in node/22 I'd like to get the node/21's title. In node/22, there's a text field where the default value is the node/21's title. Is there any function I can use for this? Please help as I badly needed this. Thank you.

Comment: You can use code from https://www.drupal.org/project/recently_read module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` with PHP to get the URL of the last page you were on. This is not a reliable solution because not all user agents support it. plus users can manually intervene with the previous page and mess things up.

If a client side solution is sufficient for you, you can use javascript's [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).

You could use a querystring as well and append that to the URL and read it from the page you're going to.

```
website.com/secondPage?refer=lastPageIWasOn

// then grab the value from the second page
$last_page_value = isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '';

// or use drupal_get_query_parameters()

// Then do something with it
```

Or you could use cookie/session to do this

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['referrer'])) {
    $_SESSION['lastpage'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
}

// second page
$referer = isset($_SESSION['lastpage']) ? $_SESSION['lastpage'] : '';
```

This is a very common use case and StackOverflow has several questions on it with PHP. I suggest googling it. Translating it to drupal will depend on what you're doing with it.